# Wordpress Elementor doesn't load CSS styles after load post via AJAX

Tags: php, css, ajax, wordpress, elementor

I have a home page which have actually one section with something similar to "carousel". In this section I dynamically load post from custom post type using ajax. Problem is that a post is created with Elementor and file with post CSS doesn't load in "head" tag.

Does anyone know is there a possibility to load CSS file manually based on post ID? Or another way to trigger generating CSS file and include to the head?

Comment: Did you enqueue your CSS correctly? Are able to see those styles in regular posts?

Comment: CSS works correctly when I visit post via permalink. I see in header that styles loaded, but when I make a custom query and show posts in another page, styles doesn't load :/ It seems like Elementor load CSS file only on page with template for single/singluar post.

Comment: Also regular posts works great. Custom posts visited via permalink also, but not loaded manually by custom wp_query in page without single/singluar template.

Comment: Sorry but the issue is with the home page or with the single post once you click on the link? If you do a custom query in another page you need style that page according to your needs. Is not going to add styles from your Custom Post Type.

Comment: No, styles which are generated for single post by Elementor doesn't include to head tag. It means e.g. In elementor you created post with two columns and add some colors, font size etc. This is show correctly in post view, but if I load it via wp_query somewhere and inject to the page styles doesn't load and everything looks different. I checked head tag and I see that css file is not loaded.

Comment: This issue is not related to page styles. For every created template in Elementor like a post, page etc. Is generating CSS file which is include to head tag. That is how it works. In my example when I load posts via wp_query it's not including. That's my question, is there possibility to force load that generated CSS file manually?